# Scroll to comment after posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like the user to automatically scroll to the comment the user just made on an article. The user submits his/her comment via an Ajax call. Via Javascript I check whether the user gets a success-msg or not. If the user does, it means he/she has filled in everything correctly. Then its time to refresh the page and jump to his/her comment.

URL would look like: domain.com/article/#comment-73

Now my question is, how do I jump to his/her comment via Javascript? This is my current piece of JS

```
$(function() { 
    $(document).on('click',"#send-comment-btn",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/db-requests/db-post-comment-on-article.php",
            data: $("#comment-recaptcha-form").serialize(),
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   comment_on_article(data,textStatus,jqXHR);  }
        });
    });
});

function comment_on_article(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
    alert(data);

    if (data == "comment_wrong_captcha") {
        //throw error message
    }

    if (data == "comment_finished_success") {   
        $('#comment-captcha-handler').removeClass('error-msg');
        $('#comment-captcha-handler').text('Your comment has been posted!');
        $('#comment-captcha-handler').addClass('success-msg');
        $('#comment-captcha-handler').slideDown(400);

        setTimeout(function (){
            location.reload(); //Jump to comment after reload????
            $("#comment-article-dialog").dialog( "close" );
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the point of submitting the comment in ajax if you have to reload ? :-/

Comment: So the new comments appear. But I guess I can load them into a div and have the div refresh when a new comment has been submitted.

Comment: That is what I would do, and then use `$('html, body').scrollTop($newComment);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that you want to refresh the page, you could do this with pure html by having your server-side code add an anchor to each post like:

```
<a id="post_POST_ID"></a>
```

and append to the "refresh" url a #post_POST_ID
This will make the browser jump down to have the row where you have your anchor in the top-left corner

Comment: Thats what I've been trying, but I cant get JS to recognize the comment id.. :|

Comment: You do not need javascript for this, this is a browser/html thing. You are in fact refreshing the page with a call like window.location = (your url) right?

Comment: Btw, why don't you just validate the input client-side and do a regular POST (with a submit button). You need to validate the input server-side as well, but if a user tampers with your javascript just to post malicious data then i don't think you need to care about him or her not having his comment being posted :P

Comment: How have you structured your return data? What do you get when you do alert(data)? I would format it something like: SUCCESSORFAILURMESSAGE;POSTID and do a var dataSplit = data.split(';'); and read the message from dataSplit[0] and the id from dataSplit[0]

Comment: I would also use JSON, if you have the time/interest you should read about it. However if this is a small friday project and you can't be bothered string split works just as fine (read: learn JSON, it's worth it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.scrollTo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp):

```
// Plain javascript 1:
window.scrollTo(x, y);

// Plain javascript 2:
window.location = '#comment-72'; // #=hash, not like jQuery's ID-selector

// jQuery (animated):
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: x }, 1000);

// jQuery (animated) to certain element:
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#yourElement').offset().top }, 1000);
```